# Initializing list of ints. Interpreter returns "ValueError: invalid litteral for int()"

Tags: python, list, io

## Trying to make a list of ints the user inputs. Inerpreter is returning "ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10:"

I'm somewhat new to python and I'm practicing on a website called "geeks for geeks". [Here](https://practice.geeksforgeeks.org/problems/first-negative-integer-in-every-window-of-size-k/0) is a link to the problem I'm working on.
The goal of the exercise is to print the first negative integer in a sub array of user specified size. When I try to append the user inputs to the list, the interpreter is giving me a value error. It's obviously not a type error but I can't figure out what kind of input could be given to the program to give it that error. The inputs are on a file on geeks for geek's servers so I can only test on inputs I've made.

```
# This file is for a programing practice exercise of geeksforgeerks.org
# The exercise is first negative int in window of size k

# selecting number of test cases
T = int(input())
for t in range(T):
    # initializing array
    n = int(input())
    arr = []
    while n > 0:
        arr.append(int(input().strip()))
        n-=1
    k = int(input())
    win = 0 # index of first element in widow subarray
    # terminate loop when the window can't extend further
    while win < len(array) - k -1:
        # boolean for no negatives found
        noNeg = True
        for i in range(win, k):
            if arr[i] < 0:
                print(arr[i])
                noNeg = False
                break
            elif i == k-1 and noNeg:
                # 0 if last sub arr index reached and found no negs
                print(0)
        win+=1
```

The interpreter is giving the following error on line 11:

```
print(int(input().strip()))
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '-8 2 3 -6 10'
```

Comment: If you are using only numbers, why do you use `strip()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The input data contains multiple numbers on the same line. `input()` returns a whole line of input, and when you call `int(input().strip())` you're trying to parse that whole line as a single number.

You need to split it at whitespace. So instead of a `while` loop, you can use:

```
arr = map(int, input().strip().split())
```

Comment: Unfortunately `map` is not a method of `list`, so this doesn't work. I also don't recommend using `map` since the behaviour is inconsistent between Python 2 and 3, and causes problems in some situations.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're inputting multiple integers, `int()` won't know how to convert them - it expects a single integer to be contained in the string. You'll want to split up the string and then convert:

```py
Ts = [int(word) for word in input().strip().split(" ")]
```

Note that this will give you a list instead of a single integer.

Answer (score 0):

you are feeding the input with multiple integers, you can extend your array at line 11 with your desired values:

```
arr = []
arr.extend(map(int, input().strip().split()))
# input: -8 2 3 -6 10
```

output:

```
[-8, 2, 3, -6, 10]
```